# How to compile 32-bit Wine applications on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, wine

Trying to compile a 32-bit Wine application (`winegcc -m32`) on Ubuntu 20.10 fails at the linking stage with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: relocatable linking with relocations from format elf64-x86-64
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/libwinecrt0.a(stub.o)) to format elf32-i386 (xxx.o) is not supported
```

which comes from the installed `libwinecrt0.a` being the 64-bit version.

According to `apt-file search libwinecrt0.a`, the library's relevant APT package is [`libwine-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libwine-dev). However as its dependencies seem to require replacing the C library(???), it can't be installed:

```
$ sudo apt install libwine-dev:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev:i386 : Depends: linux-libc-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Therefore, how can one compile (and link) 32-bit Wine applications on 64-bit Ubuntu using APT packages?

Answer (score 0):

I have currently circumvented the issue by manually [downloading](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/i386/libwine-dev/download) and installing the 32-bit `.deb`:

```
sudo dpkg -i libwine-dev_5.0-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

This get `winegcc -m32` to find the right library and successfully build 32-bit applications but is far from ideal as I now have a broken APT setup:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwine-dev:i386 : Depends: libc6-dev:i386 but it is not installed or
                             libc6.1-dev:i386 but it is not installable or
                             libc0.3-dev:i386 but it is not installable or
                             libc0.1-dev:i386 but it is not installable or
                             libc-dev:i386
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

A better solution is therefore needed ...